# How do I clear out a user object attribute in Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Suppose you have connected to Active Directory using the simple syntax:

```
string adPath = "LDAP://server.domain.com/CN=John,CN=Users,dc=domain,dc=com";
DirectoryEntry userEntry = Settings.GetADEntry(adPath);
```

Now, you find that you would like to see an attribute for that user.
Let's try to display the mail attribute (which stands for email address):

```
Console.WriteLine("User's mail attribute is " + userEntry.Properties["mail"]);
```

How can I delete the mail attribute value, since setting it to an empty string will not throw an error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It turns out to be pretty simple, albeit not very commonly used...

```
string adPath = "LDAP://server.domain.com/CN=John,CN=Users,dc=domain,dc=com";
DirectoryEntry userEntry = Settings.GetADEntry(adPath);
userentry.Properties["mail"].Clear();
userentry.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Perfect solution without having the use the Invoke with a method name. Cheers!

Comment: Years later and still useful in a critical scenario. Regards.

Comment: Thankyou! I wonder why .Clear() works but using userentry.Properties["mail"].Value = "" wouldn't work.

Comment: Be aware that you can not clear an proppertie with a null value. It will throw an runtime error.

Comment: @Pieter You mean that in case it throws an error, you have to put an empty string in it as an alternative?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure that you can delete it since user objects usually follow a company schema but maybe something like the following will work:

```
userEntry.Properties["mail"] = null;
```

or maybe:

```
userEntry.Invoke("Put", "mail", null);
```

then:

```
userEntry.CommitChanges();
```