# Programmatically clear or reset the Manager attribute field of AD user object to blank

Tags: active-directory

how do I programmatically clear or reset the Manager attribute field of AD user object to blank. I understand that this field only takes DN as a value. I tried to populate the field with NULL and it does not take that. Any language is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was already answered here: [How do I clear out a user object attribute in Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197786/how-do-i-clear-out-a-user-object-attribute-in-active-directory/1213152#1213152)