Delete SidHistory of AD Object from Domain Controller using c#
I am looking for a way to remove the SidHistory from Active Directory.
I have tried clearing the attribute using directory services with no success
I am able to achieve it using PowerShell, but I want to achieve it in c#
Below is the working PowerShell
Get-ADUser USERNAME -properties sidhistory | foreach {Set-ADUser $_ -remove @{sidhistory=$_.sidhistory.value}}


Would you be alright with simply running the Powershell script inside C#?

Alternatively does this work? (property set as sidhistory_)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197786/how-do-i-clear-out-a-user-object-attribute-in-active-directory
